# cloud vs HDFS for Big Data staging area

Tags: amazon-s3, hdfs, bigdata

What are the advantages and Disadvantages of having HDFS as a staging area for Big Data of 20 TB.

Which is best staging persistant layer. can we use HDFS or shall we opt for s3 cloud. Kindly share your expertise.

my findings:

HDFS has been designed to store massive amounts of data and support batch mode (OLAP) whereas Cassandra was designed 
for online transactional use-cases (OLTP).

The current recommendation for server density is 1TB/node for spinning disk and 3TB/node when using SSD.

In the Cassandra 3.x series, the storage engine has been rewritten to improve node density. Furthermore there are a few JIRA tickets 
to improve server density in the future.

There is a limit right now for server density in Cassandra because of:

repair. With an eventually consistent DB, repair is mandatory to re-sync data in case of failures. 
The more data you have on one server, the longer it takes to repair (more precisely to compute the Merkle tree, a binary tree of digests). 
But the issue of repair is mostly solved with incremental repair introduced in Cassandra 2.1

compaction. With an LSM tree data structure, any mutation results in a new write on disk so compaction is necessary to get rid of 
deprecated data or deleted data. The more data you have on 1 node, the longer is the compaction. There are also some solutions to address this issue, 
mainly the new DateTieredCompactionStrategy that has some tuning knobs to stop compacting data after a time threshold. 
There are few people using DateTiered compaction in production with density up to 10TB/node

node rebuild. Imagine one node crashes and is completely lost, you'll need to rebuild it by streaming data from other replicas. 
The higher the node density, the longer it takes to rebuild the node

load distribution. The more data you have on a node, the greater the load average (high disk I/O and high CPU usage). 
This will greatly impact the node latency for real time requests. Whereas a difference of 100ms is negligible for a batch 
scenario that takes 10h to complete, it is critical for a real time database/application subject to a tight SLA

```
Doubts: will s3 is better or HDFS?
```

Comment: It will be good if you can mention the research that you have done and your exact doubts

Comment: @AbhishekGarg: Updated my findings, but still confused whether to go for HDFS or s3. as i am planning to do visualization on powerbi. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you are confusing Cassandra as an HDFC system which is wrong. Also, I don't think you should be comparing Cassandra and an HDFS system. They have exactly opposite use case.

Cassandra is used when you have a high throughput of writes and reads are limited. It is very difficult to run map-reduce operations in Cassandra as you will be limited by partition and clustering keys.
HDFS is mainly used for map-reduce jobs where you are uploading files in a pre-defined format and you want to run analytical queries on any column which may or may not be partitioning key.

> Doubts: will s3 is better or HDFS?

S3 is an HDFS system hosted on cloud. So I am assuming whether cloud HDFS is better or local HDFS. It depends on your use case. But using S3 gives you many advantages of almost infinite scalability. If your data is present in S3 you can use AWS EMR to run your map-reduce jobs. They give a high level of monitoring.  These things are difficult to do if you are running a local HDFS.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-gs.html) is a good tutorial that you should read.